# How can I identify an element from a list within another list

Tags: python, nested, nested-lists

I have been trying to make a block of code that finds the index of the largest bid for each item. Then I was going to use the index as a way to identify the person who paid that much moneys name. However no matter what i try I can't link the person and what they have gained from the auction together. Here is the code I have been writing: It has to be able to work with any information inputted

```
def sealedBids():
    n = int(input('\nHow many people are in the group? '))#determines loop lengths
    z = 0#meant to act as a counter in while loops
    g = []#meant to store the names of all the people/players
    s = []#meant to store name of all items being bidded on
    b = []#meant to store all bids made
    f = []#meant to store the each persons fair share
    w = []#meant to store the highest bid for each item
    q = []#trying to get it to store person linked to whatever they won

    while z < n:#Process: to make the list nest lists
        b.append([])
        z = z + 1
    z = 0

    while z < n:
        g.append(input('Enter a bidders name: '))#Input: Persons name
        z = z + 1                                #Process: store name in g[] list
    z = 0

    i = int(input('How many items are being bid on?'))#determines so loop lengths

    while z < i:
        s.append(input('Enter the name of an item: '))#input: Name of item
                                                          #process: stores names in s[] list
        w.append(z)#was going to swap the info inside with the info I wanted
        z = z + 1
    z = 0
    for j in range(n):#specifies which persons bid your taking
        for k in range(i):#specifies which item is being bid on
            b[j].append(int(input('How much money has {0} bid on the {1}? '.format(g[j], s[k]))))#input: takes bid for certain item
                                                                                                       #process: stores bid in b[] list
        print(' ')#adds a space when questions are being asked so it doesn't look crunched up

    for j in range(n):#calculates fair share
        f.append(sum(b[j])/n)#add a persons total bids then divides it by number of people bidding

    for j in range(i):#meant to change the item after every bid is compared to stored highest bid
        for k in range(n):#meant to change to a different persons bid to find out who bid the most money on a particular item
            if w[j] < b[k][j]:#compares stored highest bid for particular item to each persons bid
                w[j] = b[k][j]#if highest bid is smaller then highest bid changes to the bid that was larger
                q.append(k)#trying to get it to store indentifier for whoever has highest bid so that I can use it later to link it with highest bid somehow
    print(g)#meant to check outcome
    print(s)#meant to check outcome
    print(w)#meant to check outcome
    print(q)#meant to check outcome
    print(b)#meant to check outcome

print(f)#meant to check outcome
```

any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: Variables with descriptive names would help a lot in making the intention of your code clear. Sample input with expected output might help, too.

Comment: You have completely managed to subvert Python's self-documenting nature. Impressive.

Comment: "It has to be able to work with any information inputted". You're going to need a bigger boat.

Comment: are there any modules that would help makes this easier to manage. If so just list them and I'll research the rest. It's due in a few hours T.T

Comment: Alex: Tag this as homework then, and learn not to procrastinate.

Comment: You might also want to avoid casting your bid inputs as `int` unless you want to ignore non-whole dollar amounts.

Comment: My advice is to learn some ways to make your code more readable. This applies as much to homework code where your marker will appreciate readability or in the workplace where your colleagues will appreciate it and so will you if have to return to it after a year. First way: stop using single letter variable names.

Answer (score 1):

You can use other structure for your bids. Instead of using different lists synchronized by index, you can use dictionary and python tuples. Maybe something like this:

```
items_bids = { 
  item1:  [ (bidder1, amount), (some_other_bidder, amount), ... ],
  item2:  [ (bidder1, amount), (some_other_bidder, amount), ... ],
  .
  .
  .
}
```

Then retrieving max. bids for each item is easy:

```
for item, bids in items_bids.iteritems():
    print max(bids, key=lambda x: x[1])
```

You may design your data structure differently as this one has fast insert of bids but needs more time to retrieve the highest bid. Also retrieving all bids made by one bidder would be more work for the computer.

And for more maintainable code, you may use some objects with named fields instead of tuples.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be easiest to use dictionaries with the names as keys, that way you can see what's going on:

```
group_size = 3
bidders = ('Alice', 'Bob', 'Eve')
items = ('Pipe', 'Wrench')

bids = dict(((item ,dict(((bidder, 0) for bidder in bidders))) for item in items))

#>>> print bids
#{'Pipe': {'Bob': 0, 'Alice': 0, 'Eve': 0},
# 'Wrench': {'Bob': 0, 'Alice': 0, 'Eve': 0}}

#get the money amounts
for item in bids:
    for bidder in bids[item]:
        bids[item][bidder] = int(raw_input('How much money has {0} bid on the {1}?'.format(bidder, item)))

highest_bidders = dict((item, bidder) for item in bids for bidder in bids[item]
                        if bids[item][bidder] == max(bids[item].itervalues()))
print highest_bidders
```

Answer (score 0):

This is horrible code - try this:

```
def sealedBids():
  n = input('\nHow many people are in the group? ')
  assert isinstance(n, int)
  bidders = {}
  for i in range(n):
    bidders[raw_input('Enter a bidders name: ')] = {}
  n = input('How many items are being bid on?')
  assert isinstance(n, int)
  bid_items = {}
  for i in range(n):
    bid_items[raw_input('Enter a item name: ')] = {}
  del n
  f = []
  for bidder, bidder_bids in bidders.items():
    for bid_item, bid_item_bids in bid_items.items():
      bid = input('How much money has %s bid on the %s? '%(bidder, bid_items)
      assert isinstance(bid, int)
      bidder_bids[bid_item] = bid
      bid_item_bids[bidder] = bid
    print ''
    f.append(sum(bidder_bids.values())/len(bidders)) # what is this for?
  for bid_item, bid_item_bids in bid_items.items():
    inv_bid_item_bids = dict(map(lambda item: (item[1],item[0]),bid_item_bids.items()))
    high_bid = max(inv_bid_item_bids.keys())
    high_bidder = inv_bid_item_bids[high_bid]
    bid_items[bid_item] = (high_bidder, high_bid)
```